# Expected a statement Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

I'm getting an **Expected a Statement** error in this else statement

```
if (surface == NULL);
     std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
else 
{
    optimizedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(surface, windowSurface->format, 0);
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

remove the `;` after `if`. `if (surface == NULL);` should be `if (surface == NULL)`